# What is this plant with bean-like structure at the base of its stem?

Tags: identification, houseplants

A friend of mine has bought this plant from Lidl in Romania and it doesn't have a label.

The green stuff at the base of the stem looks like a germinated coffee seed, but it's not. The height of the "coffee bean" is 4 cm (1.6 inches) and the height of the plant is 12 cm (4.7 inches).

Do you know what it is?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This plant is [Castanospermum australe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castanospermum), also known as Moreton Bay Chestnut or Blackbean. I do not have any merit in its identification as my friend received the answer from another person, but I figured it can't hurt to post the answer here for future users that will be searching for it.

Comment: Alina, I'm glad you posted this even though you know what it is. The question is a well written identification question. It's a cool plant, and unusual, especially in some parts of the world. I've never heard of it, and I'm not the only one! Also, answering your own question is encouraged.